# What does "ne plus à avoir à" mean?

Tags: sens

"Dans ce cas-là, tu dois vite choisir alors. Vas-tu rapidement te décider pour **ne plus à avoir à** en parler?"

I don't understand why the additional "à" is required instead of saying "ne plus avoir à".

Comment: Did you get this from an online location? Online stuff often has mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, [ne plus à avoir à](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ne+plus+%C3%A0+avoir+%C3%A0%2Cne+plus+avoir+%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cne%20plus%20avoir%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0) is not used.

"Vas-tu rapidement te décider pour ne plus à avoir à en parler?" comprises an error; in the positive we must have, taking a simple example, "assez frais pour avoir à en parler" and in the negative, therefore, "assez vieux pour ne plus avoir à en parler". The syntax  is the same; therefore there is an error. You must say "Vas-tu rapidement te décider pour ne plus avoir à en parler?".

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like a mistake, simply. And anyway, even without the `à`, the sentence seems quite contrived.

I'd more naturally replace `pour ne plus avoir à en parler` by `et qu'on n'en parle plus`